# How to prepare eggs in shape suited for bagel?

Tags: eggs, bagels

I often buy an egg bagel from the local coffee shop. The egg is cooked to a shape that is perfect for the bagel. From my observation it is a scrambled mixture that goes into a small glass bowl, and then into the microwave.

Any more specific advice would be awesome on how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cook an egg in the microwave, slow and at low power. It takes about four minutes at 30% power for two eggs in a round plastic container. It was perfect!

Comment: 30% of what? Microwaves vary in maximum power by more than 30%.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You'll have to eggsperiment.

Answer (score 12):

It's actually quite simple; you just use a circular cookie cutter like this one:

[image: Cookie Cutter]

You can find these at any cookware store.  It's easier to work with the ones that don't have handles, for what I hope are obvious reasons.  If you buy a [whole set](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004S1CI) then you can almost certainly find one that's exactly the right size for your bagel.

Just put the cookie cutter into your fry pan and crack the egg into them for a fried egg, or beat them separately and pour them in for scrambled.  Generally you won't actually want to *scramble* them because you're aiming for something that holds together, so just let it set on one side and then flip it, or make it like a granny omelette (lift up the set edges and tilt the pan to get the un-set egg over to the edge of the ring).

The whole microwaving thing you see at coffee shops is just because they have a hundred of them in storage and don't have time to actually cook them to order.  They're just heating an already-cooked egg, not actually cooking it in the microwave.  You shouldn't need to use the microwave at home.

Comment: I'm not so sure about them heating already-cooked eggs.  I've been to places that ladle in the eggs into their plastic containers, then microwave that.  Also see : http://scientopia.org/blogs/scicurious/2010/09/11/grad-student-eating-in-style-breakfast-sandwich/

Comment: Won't microwaving an egg make it all rubbery?  *shudder*

Comment: @Joe: Some people may microwave eggs, but I've seen them make the breakfast sandwiches right in front of me at a few different chains and unless I was hallucinating, the eggs were already cooked before they went in there.  They weren't in a bowl, they were wrapped in wax paper or something.

Comment: @Mrs. Garden: Yeah, I really wouldn't recommend the microwave for cooking eggs.  Reheating them for 10 seconds or so usually won't hurt them too much, though.

Comment: I'd go the cheap route and wonder down the canned fruit isle of your local megamart.  there are a lot of different sized cans (I grabbed a set of 4 short pinapple tins which were the perfect size from crumpets).  You might be able to find a nice cheap set of rings if you just pop the top and bottom off.  I would suggest using one of those can openers that leave no sharp edges.

Comment: @Aaronut : we go to different chains then.  The last time I saw this being done (starting from a liquid) was Chesapeake Bagel Bakery, specifically the one near George Mason University (where I was attending some workshops).  The meats they had *were* pre-cooked and kept in a heated container; I don't believe they microwaved them as they were already warm.

Comment: @FoodTasted: I'd honestly just shell out the $1 for a cookie cutter, but I guess if you're on a *really* tight budget then a short can will work too.

Comment: @Joe: I'll take a closer look next time I need to eat one of those things, as it's possible I imagined it, but I am 95% positive that I saw them take out pre-cooked egg.  It's probably already warm, too, they just get it "hot" so it'll melt the cheese.

Comment: @FoodTasted- You're my new hero

Comment: there are three competing types of product in the quickserve market for eggs, one set is a round, precooked disk, the second is a jug of prescrambled eggs that you portion and cook, and the third is the flat sheets that you bake in the oven. First and third are cooked ahead, then kept warm, although I'm sure some people are cooking to order in a microwave. And you can cook an egg in the microwave suitable for a sandwich  (It comes out the consistancy of the egg on the mcdonalds egg mcmuffin).

Answer (score 1):

Noah's Bagels does not use pre-cooked eggs in their breakfast products, like their egg mitts. They pour the raw egg into a plastic container, looks just like a tupperware-type, and microwave it. Subway does use a pre-cooked egg.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried something off the Internet for the first time and I will be making them many more times! Put a blob of butter in a microwave safe cup, I used the fake stuff with yogurt in it. Microwave it for 20 seconds, swirl it around in the cup coating the sides part way up. Crack 1 or 2 eggs in it, I did 2 but with a soup cup, add a splash of milk or not, wish it with a fork microwave for 90 seconds.

I JUST finished this 10 minutes ago yummy. I have a 1000 watt microwave. You could put it on a bagel with a slice of ham and or melt some cheese in it. I just put a little pepper on it and ate it right out of the cup with a different fork.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about cooking an egg in the microwave but Bed Bath & Beyond sells rings you can use to make the eggs whatever shape you want. I have seen hearts, rectangles, and circles. If you want to go a little bit old fashioned use a piece of toast and cut out the middle to the size that fits. I have scrambled, made mini-omlettes, and fried eggs with toast and the little round rings.

-Everytime I have tried to cook an egg in the microwave I get exploded eggs all over the inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to get an [Egg Poacher](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000P6FD3I). I'm still not sure how I personally feel about this cooking method, as I'm not a fan of cooking with plastics and silicone; but I've had friends swear by them. It could be a bit of a change from your scrambles, putting a little vinegar in the water also helps keep the egg whites together if you don't have something like these.

Comment: There are metal egg poachers available that are meant to be submerged in a saucepan.  But this will obviously make poached eggs, not fried or scrambled; I love Eggs Benedict and Florentine myself, but I'm not sure that the OP wants a leaky breakfast sandwich.

Comment: The metal ones work nicely, but seem to be only available sized for three eggs. Eggs Benedict for two usually implies FOUR eggs, so I took a tinsnips to an old muffin tin and made a four-holer. Be sure to fold over the sharp edges with pliers and a hammer.

Answer (score 0):

I just went to Einstein Bros and wondered the exact same thing. Came home and experimented a bit and found the following method worked perfectly:

1. Spray a small bowl or microwave safe dish with cooking spray.
2. Break a single egg into the bowl. Puncture the yolk.
3. Sprinkle with salt and pepper.

I got the best results by cooking for 60 seconds at 50% microwave power (its a 1000w microwave).

And it just slides out.

Its my go to method to cook up a quick egg now. Its fast and very little clean up.

Next I am going to try variations like sprinkiling cheese, paprika, bacon crumbles, etc on  top.

Also check out http://www.buzzfeed.com/arielknutson/easy-ways-to-cooks-eggs-in-a-microwave for more microwave egg reciepes

Answer (score 0):

As said low & slow in the microwave.  I put them in a round small oven safe bowl. Salt & pepper. Bake in oven. You can scramble them first then bake for a fluffy scrambled egg. I use small round oven or microwave safe bowls for this.  Works well. 350f in oven. Bacon & biscut at same time in oven.

Comment: It's really difficult to understand when you're talking about a microwave and when you're talking about an oven in this answer. Could you edit it to clarify?